# SQL Server key value pair convert varchar to numeric without exceptions

Tags: sql-server, parsing, text-parsing

I'm looking for tips on putting together a user defined function to convert a varchar to numeric.  The trick is i'm after one that converts common text representations of strings to numeric.  Also, if it can't be parsed as a numeric, i'd like it to return NULL rather than throwing an error and stopping the query.

Examples:

- varchar '10%' should parse as numeric 0.1 (No remove % sign and divide by 100)
- varchar '$1,00.1234' should parse as numeric 100.1234 (remove $ sign and ,)
- varchar '$1k' should parse as numeric 1000  (k converts to multiply by 1 thousand)
- varchar '$1M' should parse as numeric 1000000  (m converts to multiply by 1 Million)
- varchar '$1B' should parse as numeric 1000000000 (b converts to multiply by 1 Billion)
- varchar '100   ' should parse as numeric 1000  (LTrim & RTrim)
- varchar 'Random Text' should parse as numeric NULL  (Null won't thrown an error)

Answer (score 2):

I'd suggest you use a CLR function to parse to this complexity. Then fix the data

You have a mix of currency, percentages, mixed decimal/separator formatting, in addition to non-numeric values.